# 'ion-auto-complete' is not a known element:

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm trying to use ionic auto complete with my ionic 3 app , 
how ever , it shows this error message

> 'ion-auto-complete' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'ion-auto-complete' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ion-auto-complete' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message. ("
>
> [ERROR ->]

what i did is :

```
npm install ionic2-auto-complete --save
```

then added

```
{ AutoCompleteModule } from 'ionic2-auto-complete';
```

to my `app.module.ts`
then added

```
<ion-auto-complete></ion-auto-complete>
```

to HTML

Comment: How did you include the component? Which library is this?

Comment: npm install ionic2-auto-complete --save then add import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'ionic2-auto-complete'; to app.module.ts , then add <ion-auto-complete></ion-auto-complete>
to my HTML

Comment: Try including in your ionicPage instead in ionic 3.  Also please use [edit] link to add info to your question

Comment: i've included it in my ionicPage and still not working

Comment: did you add to ionicPageModule imports array in ngModule?

Comment: Yes i've added the ionicPageModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to add the import in the app.module.ts, you have to declare the AutoCompleteModule in the import section:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    PipesModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    AutoCompleteModule
  ],
  declarations: [MiPerfilPage]
})
```

If it doesn't work, try to do the same thing but in the PageModule.ts you want to use it.
You can read this post too:
https://github.com/kadoshms/ionic2-autocomplete/issues/109

Comment: that's true , and also i need to add the page to declarations